# Android: What will happen, if I open an URL pointing to Google Play if a user doesn't have the market app installed?

Tags: android, browser, android-intent, installation

Not all Android devices have the Google Play app installed.
So, what will happen, if a I open a Google Play page in the browser by intent?
Can the user still download the app?

I can't test it, because all my devices have the Google Play app installed as part of the Android OS.

Here is the code in question:

```
        String url = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.my_app";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
```

Will the user be able to install the app?

Comment: Hey I would like to know which devices doesnot have GooglePlay installed.

Comment: The Kindle Fire for one, and some Google TVs. I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Some manufacturer dont install the Market app as part of their OS, especially if they have their own markets. Some Custom ROMs, for example Cyanogen dont include the market app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The play store will open in the browser, but the user will still be unable to download and install, as his/her device won't show up as valid in the list of play store devices that it can be installed on (remember that the browser version of the play store never downloads, but instead just sends it via cloud installing to various devices). Your only option would be, if there is no play store installed, to offer them a download link for sideloading.

Comment: It is a custom banner ad, so I could test if the market app is installed. Do you know the package name of the market app?

Answer (score 0):

It will open the browser at this page.  I'm not sure if the user will be able to push the app to their device if they haven't got the market installed.